# How to find 'code' in spotify/authorize endpoint response

Tags: python, json, api, spotify

getting my hands dirty trying to authenticate usage for spotify api.

Right now, here's my code. I'm trying to parse the response to the authorize endpoint.

```
####################################### Package Imports #######################################

import os
import sys
import requests
import json
from dotenv import load_dotenv

####################################### Env Setup #######################################

sys.path.insert(0, os.environ['HOME'])

dotenv_path = os.environ['HOME'] + '/prod.env'

load_dotenv(dotenv_path, override=True)    
locals().update(os.environ)

####################################### Main #######################################

main_url = 'https://api.spotify.com/'
auth_url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"
token_url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
uri = 'http://localhost:8888/callback'


user_auth_headers = {
    "client_id": spotify_client_id,
    "response_type": "code",
    "redirect_uri": uri
}

auth_response = requests.get(auth_url, headers=user_auth_headers)
```

Essentially, I'm supposed to fetch a 'code' response value from `auth_response`. So I can use it in the below request to get auth token

```
token_headers={
    "grant_type":"authorization_code",
    "client_id": spotify_client_id,
    "client_secret": spotify_client_secret
    "code": code
}

token = requests.post(auth_response.url, headers=token_headers)
```

However, running `print(auth_response.json())` to try extract the json from of `auth_response`, I receive this error     `raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)`

What am I missing here? Will a get request to `"https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"` not accomodate json?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

**auth_response.status_code**

200

**auth_response.content**

```
b'\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html id="app" lang="en" dir="ltr" ng-csp ng-strict-di>\n<head>\n  <meta charset="utf-8">\n  <title ng-bind="(&#39;loginTitle&#39; | localize) + &#39; - Spotify&#39;">Spotify</title>\n  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">\n  <base href="/">\n  <link rel="icon" href="https://accounts.scdn.co/sso/images/favicon.ace4d8543bbb017893402a1e9d1ac1fa.ico">\n  <link href="https://accounts.scdn.co/sso/css/index.f154bf48b3e0d0631bea.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet">\n\n  <script defer src="https://accounts.scdn.co/sso/js/index.f154bf48b3e0d0631bea.js" sp-bootstrap></script>\n  <meta ng-non-bindable sp-bootstrap-data=\'{"phoneFeatureEnabled":false,"previewEnabled":false,"user":false,"tpaState":"AQDUR8Dp61PYT5mAj61uU7DjKgmzBO8dlKMQsbpLL3NBR7jU+XykYABnmoC4ZDRbv3eIhl3s+t1bksk8J9ojKDSIfXLRcrFaz9iP95iK5dJEBT1Yay5MA8g+29fxevkBShJC8vJpVFmFV+EG6dpz1mJ0k+FvNW5miWrtOkBm2msF7Hw4AbUIFMt8ygUjc0vdgjYlqQWtZXTgcc3Lh+Z+/6NkcSOnoQ==","BON":["0","0",-246496388]}\'>\n</head>\n<body ng-controller="LoginController">\n  <div ng-include="template"></div>\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

Comment: What is the output of `auth_response.status_code` and `auth_response.content`?

Comment: I edited the post reflecting the outputs of these results

Comment: Any thoughts @BrokenBenchmark?

Comment: You're making a `GET` request, which then returns HTML. Your code then assumes it's JSON and attempts to parse it, at which point it contains an error. Can you tell me what you're trying to extract from Spotify's webpage / what endpoint in [Spotify's API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/) you're actually trying to authenticate through?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark This is the endpoint I'm using in the request: `https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize`. The goal is to fetch a 'code' parameter to then pass in a request to `"https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
` to get my access token.

Comment: What are you trying to extract from `/authorize`? You're trying to parse HTML as JSON, and that's causing your error.

Comment: I'm hoping to get a `code` value, but I'm not sure where to fetch it from. This `code` value is expected in the payload sent to get the access token.

Comment: Where does the Spotify API documentation describe a `code` value, and/or why do you have reason to suppose that this value must come from this specific endpoint?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Sorry for late response, I have been ill. If you look at the authorization flow [link](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/) here, you can see that I should receive a callback url with my code, to send to the auth_token endpoint. It should appear as so `https://my-domain.com/callback?code=NApCCg..BkWtQ&state=34fFs29kd09` but I can't find a link in the response like that anywhere. Am I maybe utilizing the wrong guide in the docs?

Comment: I would love a response to this as well. I am stuck in the same step.